# props updated with state data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on react js and I have one data coming from parent I am storing state of child and I am updating that child data.now my problem is it is updating my parent data as well in react way it is updating state and props both are updating.
I thought props are read only. why it is getting updated?
below is my code

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      MixData: this.props.allYearData,

    };
  }
 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({

     MixData: this.props.allYearData
    });
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      channelMixData: nextProps.allYearData
    });
  }
//here I am updating value
  updateValuePercent = key => {
    let reduceValue = 0.005 / this.props.mix.length;
    let MixData = [...this.state.MixData];
    let updatedData = MixData.map(data => {

        data.mix.map(name => {

            name.volume =
              key.type === 'Inc'
                ? name.volume + 0.005
                : name.volume - 0.005;

        });
        return data;

      return data;
    });

    this.setState({ MixData: updatedData });
  };
 render() {
    if (
      !this.props.allYearData ||

    )
      return null;
console.log("this state and empty data....",this.state.MixData,this.props.allYearData);//here both data showing same value even after updating state

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example, including what the data looks like? props are not read-only, they do change, but only when data is passed down from its parent. Can you fork and update https://codesandbox.io/s/kpwn08z6v plz

Comment: data u have added it's proper just the thing is I pass this data from my api call to reducer and reducer's state I am passing this to component

Comment: In my example, when we update state, the props and data do differ as expected. Do you have a loop? update state, call API, pull data from API and update parent?

Comment: no. it is just updating state.not calling API. actually there will be 2 button. the code I have provided in `close` method it is for `cancel` button so no API call will trigger. so no update in parent

Comment: In your example also it is changing data on both state as well as props..

Comment: It's not as far as I can see. Clicking an item updates state, but props remain. That's what the UI is showing two (different) JSON data objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155899/discussion-between-lowcool-and-garry-taylor).